# How to make x-axis tickmarks span the entire bar chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to create a bar chart. I need this bar chart to eventually look like the chart below, with the x-axis tickmarks spanning the entire width of the chart:
[image]

With my current code, the chart looks like this:
[image]

Any ideas on how to make this happen?

[Here is a fiddle with my current code.](http://jsfiddle.net/6CrEu/)

And the actual code:
HTML:

```
<div id="q2-bar" class="chart">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#q2-bar').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'bar',
                    backgroundColor:'transparent'
                },
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Label', 'Label', 'Label', 'Label', 'Label', 'Label', 'Label', 'Label', 'Label', 'Label', 'Label'],
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    },
                    tickLength: 500,
                    lineColor: 'transparent',
                    labels: {
                        style: {
                            color: '#ffffff'
                        }
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    labels: {
                        overflow: 'justify',
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    gridLineColor: 'transpartent',
                },
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: '%'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    bar: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '{y}%',
                            color: '#ffffff'
                        }
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Expenses Covered',
                    borderWidth: '0',
                    data: [{
                        y: 46,
                        color: '#d70081'
                    },{
                        y: 52,
                        color: '#0099cc'
                    },{
                        y: 73,
                        color: '#75ad01'
                    },{
                        y: 47,
                        color: '#ffcc00'
                    },{
                        y: 64,
                        color: '#ff6600'
                    },{
                        y: 60,
                        color: '#663399'
                    },{
                        y: 42,
                        color: '#00b99c'
                    },{
                        y: 51,
                        color: '#ff0033'
                    },{
                        y: 51,
                        color: '#0099cc'
                    },{
                        y: 60,
                        color: '#d70081'
                    },{
                        y: 81,
                        color: '#ffcc00'
                    }]
                }]
            });
```

Thanks!

Comment: I might be misunderstanding something, but what are "x-axis tickmarks"?

Comment: The white lines above and below the "Label"s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a 'gridLineWidth' and 'gridLineColor' in the x-axis.

```
xAxis: {
                categories: ['Label', 'Label', 'Label', 'Label', 'Label', 'Label', 'Label', 'Label', 'Label', 'Label', 'Label'],
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                tickLength: 500,
                lineColor: 'transparent',
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        color: '#ffffff'
                    }
                },
                gridLineWidth:'1px',
                gridLineColor:'#FFFFFF'

            },
```